# What is meant by "non-convex prior" and "sparsity-inducing prior"?

Tags: bayesian, prior, dirichlet-distribution

I was reading how to use collapsed gibbs sampling for latent dirichlet allocation in a google group and one user talked about using dirichlet priors with small hyperparameters and sum out the z variables.He argued that this leads to a highly nonconvex sparsity-inducing prior. I didn't find a good resource to explain these terms. Can anyone knows what's the meaning of "non-convex prior" and "sparsity-inducing prior"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of latent Dirichlet allocation, sparsity-inducing generally means that each document will have a small number of topics, and/or each topic a small number of words.

You can get an intuitive sense of this by sampling from symmetric Dirichlet distributions with smaller and smaller $\alpha$. Note that as $\alpha$ decreases, so too does the number of vector elements with much appreciable mass:

```
from numpy.random import dirichlet
import numpy as np

dirichlet(alpha)
#array([ 0.10676152,  0.08215308,  0.02062772,  0.02298146,  0.19103266,
#        0.00970799,  0.12679858,  0.09302878,  0.20203575,  0.14487247])

dirichlet(alpha * .5)

#array([  5.82174931e-03,   9.57244704e-03,   2.34178297e-03,
#         1.36493461e-05,   1.48232942e-01,   4.70729672e-03,
#         2.16961745e-04,   1.25516179e-01,   5.75171255e-01,
#         1.28405736e-01])

dirichlet(alpha * .1)
#array([  3.97274708e-03,   2.83228516e-05,   1.57799254e-11,
#         1.54681686e-02,   2.84177188e-03,   5.47093616e-05,
#         4.05136241e-01,   4.72963496e-03,   9.48923838e-04,
#         5.66819481e-01])
```

Comment: But how this relates to prior in the first place?

Comment: LDA places priors on the distribution for topic mixing proportions $\theta_m$ and topics $\beta_k$; these priors are $\alpha, \eta$, respectively. Put another way: Selecting a smaller value for $eta$ expresses a preference that each topic will distribute most probability over a smaller number words. Smaller $\alpha$ expresses a preference for more topically sparse documents. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, now i understand. but i still don't know about "non-convex prior". can you help me with that?

Comment: Not sure I can help. Dirichlet log-likelihood is convex in $\alpha$(see [here](http://www.msr-waypoint.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/dirichlet/minka-dirichlet.pdf) and [here](http://jonathan-huang.org/research/dirichlet/dirichlet.pdf)) so it's not clear to me what they were getting at. Did they mean that the prior was non-convex or that it induced non-convexity?